# How to kill a process group with kill in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, signals

I have a script which is much more complicated but I managed to produce a short script that exhibits the same problem.

I create a process and make it a session leader and then send `SIGINT` to it. The `kill` builtin doesn't fail but the process doesn't get killed either (i.e. the default behaviour for SIGINT is to kill). I tried with `kill -INT -pid` (which should be equivalent to what I do currently) and the `/bin/kill` command but the behaviour is the same.

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run in a new session so that I don't have to kill the shell
setsid bash -c "sleep 50" &

procs=$(ps --ppid $$ -o pid,pgid,command | grep 'sleep' | head -1)
if [[ -z "$procs" ]]; then
    echo "Couldn't find process group"
    exit 1
fi

PID=$(echo $procs | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
pgid=$(echo $procs | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

if ! kill -n SIGINT $pgid; then
    echo "kill failed"
fi

echo "done"

ps -P $pgid
```

My expectation is that the last `ps` command shouldn't report anything (as `kill` didn't report failure and hence the process should have died) but it does.

I am looking for an explanation of the above noted behaviour and how I can kill a process group (i.e. both the `bash` and the `sleep` it starts -- the setsid line above) running in a separate session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that `sleep` ignores `SIGINT`. Take a look at [the signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to) of your `sleep` command and see. On my Linux box I find:

`SigIgn: 0000000000000006`

The second bit from the right is set (6 = 4 + 2 + 0), and from the above link:

   `-->  2 = SIGINT`

Try send a `HUP`, and you'll find it does kill the sleep.

Comment: Indeed your observation is correct. But what's not clear is why `SigIgn` of `sleep` is 6 when running via `bash -c ...` but not when running sleep directly. Is it because bash ignores and hence its children inherit it? Is there a way avoid this (i.e. tell bash to not ignore SIGINT)? Regardless of it, I already +1ed for your helpful info. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you're right about inheritance. Reading the man page "When  bash  is  interactive,  in  the  absence of any traps, [...] SIGINT is caught and handled". You could use `trap` to tell it to not do that.

Comment: I tried to get bash to exit on `SIGINT` but am failing.... `setsid bash -c "trap 'echo ouch; exit 42' SIGINT; sleep 50" &`